# How to include subdirectories to autoload for Grape API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm using Grape to build an API for a Rails project (I'm mounting the grape project in rails `routes.rb` something like `mount Backend::Base => '/'`).

The files structure is something like:

`├── app
│   ├── api
│   │   └── backend
│   │       ├── base.rb
│   │       └── v1
│   │           ├── alerts.rb
│   │           ├── test
│   │           │   └── index.rb`

My `application.rb` includes:

```
config.paths.add "app/api", glob: "**/*.rb"

config.paths.add File.join('app', 'api'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '*')]
```

For `base.rb`:

```
module Backend
  class Base < Grape::API

    format :json
    prefix :api

    mount CanopyBackend::V1::Alerts
    mount CanopyBackend::V1::Test::Index

  end
end
```

My `alerts.rb`:

```
module Backend
  module V1
    class Alerts < Grape::API
      include Backend::V1::Defaults

      resource :alerts do
        get do
          "alerts"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And `test/index.rb`:

```
module Backend
  module V1
    module Test
      class Index < Grape::API
        include Backend::V1::Defaults

        resource :index do
          get do
            "index"
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Now it seems I can access `GET api/v1/alerts` but **not** `api/v1/test/index` somehow.

I tried to modify `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '*')]` in `application.rb` to make it `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '/**/')]` but without any luck.

Any help?